# Cannot pickup Gauldur amulet fragment in Geirmund's Hall

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I am having trouble retrieving the Gauldur amulet fragment from Geirmund's Hall after clearing it before I was aware of this quest. Now when I return the quest indicator points on the floor in boss' room, specifically on a patch of submerged dirt. The water is quite shallow and I am quite sure that there is nothing to pick up there.

To me it seems the quest has bugged as I killed the boss before embarking on this quest, or killed him while unaware of the quest and not picking the fragment up. How can I get around this? Is there a console command which can help me?

Comment: ive got the same bug but im on the 360

Comment: Patch 1.4 will fix this issue, at least for players who have not yet been in Geirmund's hall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can type `player.additem 0002d753 1` to add the Gauldur Amulet fragment into your inventory. If your quest doesn't advance by adding the item to your inventory, you will need to advance the quest to next stage with the command `setstage dunGauldursonQST 8`.

[Forbidden Legend Quest Details and Bug fixes](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forbidden_Legend)

Comment: Adding the amulet worked but I couldn't advance the quest. After reading this http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2244501 I'm going to try and manually completing the next step and hope the quest will advance itself.

Comment: Any solution to this for xbox users?

Answer (score 3):

I passed Geirmund's Hall before the others and this quest got bugged. This is how I completed it:

1. After having the other two fragments (1 and 3) returned to Geirmund's Hall and at the place of the marker typed to console:

   ```
   player.additem 0002d753 1
   ```

   This got me the second amulet fragment (no progress in the Journal, though).

   ```
   setstage dunGauldursonQST 9
   ```

   (This had no visible result, so I'm not sure if it was necessary.)
2. Went to Reachwater Rock (cave under a waterfall south of Karthspire).

   After opening a claw-locked door inside the quest suddenly advanced to 'Forge the amulet' or something like that. There weren't any problems till the end.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [a bug can occur (UESP wiki Forbidden Legend article talk page)](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Forbidden_Legend#Geirmund.27s_Hall_problem) if you've cleared the Geirmund's Hall dungeon or killed Sigdis Gauldurson (the boss in that dungeon) before starting the [Forbidden Legend](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forbidden_Legend) quest. If you do this, you might be unable to pick up Sigdis' Gauldur Amulet Fragment.

For platforms that can't use mods or console commands, such as Xbox 360 and PS3, to fix this you'd need to load a save where you haven't killed Sigdis Gauldurson yet nor started the Forbidden Legend quest. Then, start [the quest](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forbidden_Legend) before killing Sigdis Gauldurson.