# Why can't I pick up the Gauldur Amulet in Geirmund's hall?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I can see the quest marker that there is something to pick up. But I can't see anything and can't pick up anything. I killed Sigdis Gauldurson at several places. First I thought the amulet piece was in the water/mud and that I couldn't see it. Then I reloaded from my last save point and killed Sigdis upstairs, so could see the fragment. But I read in previous post that it is a bug. Is it possible to fix this on a PS3?

Comment: As per [Cannot pickup Gauldur amulet fragment in Geirmund's Hall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37939/4797) and [I'm unable to pick up the Gauldur Amulet fragment in Geirmund's Hall (duplicate)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38589/4797), it seems that the solution will require console commands or mods, which I believe is not possible with the PS3. Try loading to a save before you've killed *Sigdis Gauldurson*, and start the quest again.

Comment: As pointed out by galacticninja (implicitly), this is no duplicate, since this is for PS3.

Comment: @Joachim Actually, I believe this is a duplicate as per [Questions where OP has mentioned he/she is using a specific platform: how to answer, how to tag and when to close as exact duplicate?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5488/4797)

Answer (score -1):

sometimes when you are in a dungeon, things will turn invisible try looking around the pedestal it is on.

Comment: What do you mean with "things will turn invisible"? I've never had that happen to me at random. Or do you mean 'hard to see'?